# Why is the following sequence of functions ordered by asymptotic growth rates?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

Order the following expressions in increasing Θ-order. If two functions are of the same order of growth, you should state this fact.

> n log n, n<sup>−1</sup>, log n, n<sup>log n</sup>, 10n + n<sup>3/2</sup>, π<sup>n</sup>, 2<sup>n</sup>, 2<sup>log n</sup>, 2<sup>2<sup>log n</sup></sup>, log n!

Can someone explain to me why the following answer is correct?

> n<sup>−1</sup> ≪ log n ≪ 2<sup>log n</sup> ≪ n log n = log n! ≪ 10n + n<sup>3/2</sup>≪ n<sup>log n</sup> ≪ 2<sup>n</sup> = 2<sup>2<sup>log n</sup></sup> ≪ π<sup>n</sup>

Answer (score 6):

You should use the facts that:

```
lim(n->∞) f(n)/ g(n) = 0  this gives you Θ(f(n)) < Θ(g(n))
lim(n->∞) f(n)/ g(n) = c; c > 0 this gives you Θ(f(n)) = Θ(g(n))
lim(n->∞) f(n)/ g(n) = ∞  this gives you Θ(f(n)) > Θ(g(n))
```

Now using that you get:

```
lim(n->∞) n^−1 / log n = lim(n->∞) 1 / (n * log n) = 0.
```

This immediately gives you `Θ(n^−1) < Θ(log n)`

Go on with the remaining.

For some of the calculations you might find [L'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) helpful.

Answer (score 2):

So it has been a long time since I thought about these concepts (and I'm sure others will correct me if this is wrong) but I don't agree with your answer.  First off theta means bound above and below by that function.  This means 10n + n3/2, 2n, and πn are all the same theta class.  log n, 2log n, 22log n are also all the same class.  To see that n log n is the same class as log n! use [stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation). Thus you get:

```
log n = 2 log n = 22 log n ≪ n−1 = 10n + n3/2 = 2n = πn ≪ n log n = log n!
```

Now if 'n3/2' means n^(3/2) rather than 3/2*n then the order would be:

```
log n = 2 log n = 22 log n ≪ n−1 = 2n = πn ≪ n log n = log n! ≪ 10n + n3/2
```

Comment: Does n3/2 mean n to the power of 1.5? If so, wouldn't 10n + n3/2 and 2n be different class? n - 1 should definately be with 2n and πn

Comment: oh, I took it to mean n * 3/2... if it is n^(3/2) then that would be between πn  and   n log n

Comment: Correct. For all `n >= 2`, we have `n-1 <= n <= 2*(n-1)`, so it's where it belongs. If `n3/2` was meant to be `n^(3/2)`, that would be the fastest growing of these.

Comment: you are correct sir, my mistake... like I said it has been a while

Comment: thanks, there was an error with the powers, I have corrected this but I will resubmitted in order to get correct answers

Comment: To show that `n log n` and  `log n!` have the same rate of growth (that is, `θ(n log n) = θ(log n!)`), note that `n log n = log(n^n)`, and that `log(n^n) > log(n!) > log(n^n) - O(sqrt(n))` by [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

Comment: This answer is not correct and confusing based on a typo made by the author.